Updating probability after an (unlikely) event
We are considering that 1/5 of the donuts in the world are chocolate-flavored.
In a certain place, a selection of donuts has been made.
A person randomly picks a donut, and it is a chocolate donut.
What is now the probability that another donut from this selection is chocolate?
Now, what if n people each pick a donut, and all n donuts turn out to be chocolate? What is the updated probability that another donut from this selection is chocolate?
I'm looking for a clear explaination of the answer; I've asked ChatGPT and I've got something not quite satisfying (adapted for brevity):

Answer adapted from ChatGPT - not convincing except the final number.
Case when one person picks a chocolate donut
Initial Data:
()=1/5 : The prior probability that a donut is chocolate.
Using Bayes' Theorem, we have:
$P(B∣C)=\dfrac{P(C∣B)⋅P(B)​}{P(C)}$
with C the event "1 chocolate donut is picked up"
According to ChatGPT
P(C∣B)=1: If the selection is entirely chocolate donuts, the probability of picking a chocolate donut is 1.
P(C∣not B)= 1/5 : If only 1/5 of the donuts are chocolate, the probability of getting a chocolate donut is 1/5
P(C)=P(C∣B)⋅P(B)+P(C∣not B)⋅P(not B)
Calculating:
P(C) = 1 . 1/5 + 1/5 . 4/5 = 9/25
Thus, the updated probability after observing one chocolate donut is:
$P(B/C) = \dfrac{1/5}{9/25}$ = 5/9
And with a similar reasoning for n=10 it gets to $P(10C) = 1/5 + \dfrac{4}{5.5^{10}}$
and $P(B/10C)≈0.9999996$

The numbers seem OK but I'm pretty sure the reasoning is flawed (as we could expect).
But I also fail to have a correct reasoning.
For me:
P(C∣not B) = P(C∣B)=1/5 :we had 1/5 to pick a chocolate donut
But this does not lead me anywhere.

I would appreciate a clarification on this example and also if possible a generalisation of this demonstration where we consider the updated probability of the same event when it happens (or not, ie if 5 out of 12 persons had found a chocolate donut).

You'll need more information.  We have no idea what the distribution of donuts from a single vendor looks like

Or more assumptions.

While ChatGPT may be reliably consulted for entertainment purposes (only), it is not a good idea to assume that any ChatGPT work is either valid or accurate.  Further, as the previous comments indicate, the original problem, as stated, can not be solved.
